# Flat Remix theme only showing up for shell, not windows

Tags: themes

I'm having an issue. Though I've installed flat remix, it doesn't show up in the drop-down for application themes, only shell themes. Because of this, the theme isn't applying to the windows and applications. I'm using Ubuntu 20.04

[image: tweak tool]

Comment: does it have gtk folder along gnom-shell??

Comment: No, only a gnome-shell folder. But it's listed as working with Ubuntu.

Comment: gtk folder is responsible for applications theme.. that means the theme is only for gnome-shell